# R Arules Market Basket Analysis Redundant Rules Approaches

Tags: r, association-rules, apriori

Using R and arules. I see several opinions on how to remove redundant rules which give different answers.

If this is my example dataset:

```
    lhs                rhs                support confidence lift 
[1] {r7sVi9T6D1nE}  => {hN1sUFRI}         0.0013  0.80       210.9
[2] {hN1sUFRI}      => {r7sVi9T6D1nE}     0.0013  0.33       210.9
[3] {8l0QeRHU0CWLP} => {XUFbPOzrmrKJgcmi} 0.0016  0.56         5.8
[4] {9f7J8ox1}      => {YTeK1f0yQd9hvPz2} 0.0016  0.36         2.1
[5] {NCzMaUfT}      => {eByLP-ea}         0.0022  0.47        77.7
[6] {eByLP-ea}      => {NCzMaUfT}         0.0022  0.37        77.7
[7] {sUvng3}        => {8D4AhPCsnBT}      0.0016  0.36         9.2
```

The most common approach I've seen is:

```
# source: http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/association-rules
rules <- sort(rules, by = 'lift')
subset.matrix <- is.subset(rules, rules)
subset.matrix[lower.tri(subset.matrix, diag=T)] <- NA
redundant <- colSums(subset.matrix, na.rm = TRUE) >= 1
which(redundant)
rules <- rules[!redundant]
```

Outputs:

```
    lhs                rhs                support confidence lift 
[1] {r7sVi9T6D1nE}  => {hN1sUFRI}         0.0013  0.80       210.9
[2] {eByLP-ea}      => {NCzMaUfT}         0.0022  0.37        77.7
[3] {sUvng3}        => {8D4AhPCsnBT}      0.0016  0.36         9.2
[4] {8l0QeRHU0CWLP} => {XUFbPOzrmrKJgcmi} 0.0016  0.56         5.8
[5] {9f7J8ox1}      => {YTeK1f0yQd9hvPz2} 0.0016  0.36         2.1
```

However, [arules](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/arules.pdf) provides `is.redundant`:

> Provides the generic functions and the S4 method `is.redundant` to find
>   redundant rules.

If I do in RStudio console:

```
> is.redundant(rules)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Rules all show `FALSE` indicating no rules are considered redundant.

Another source shows the following approach to remove redundant rules:

```
# source: http://rstatistics.net/association-mining-with-r/
redundant <- which (colSums (is.subset (rules, rules)) > 1) # get redundant rules in vector
rules <- rules[-redundant] # remove redundant rules
```

But this produces different outputted results than above:

```
    lhs                rhs                support confidence lift
[1] {8l0QeRHU0CWLP} => {XUFbPOzrmrKJgcmi} 0.0016  0.56       5.8 
[2] {9f7J8ox1}      => {YTeK1f0yQd9hvPz2} 0.0016  0.36       2.1 
[3] {sUvng3}        => {8D4AhPCsnBT}      0.0016  0.36       9.2
```

**Which Approach Is Right And Correct?**

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the last approach is right. Looking at your output, the last approach removes the non redundant rules as well. 
For me the 1st approach gave me an empty set.